# Getting values from rails HTML view to controller to erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to get values from a HTML select input to my controller so that I can use it in a conditional erb snippet

This is the html snippet for the dropdown

```
<select id="select" name="parish" class="form-control" onchange="choice(this.value)">
  <option value="">--Select value--</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
  <option value="two">2</option> 
</select>
```

I was told to use AJAX to pass the value

```
function choice(value) {
  console.log(value)
  $.ajax({
    url: '/tickets/index',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      parish: $('#select').val()
    }
    /*success:function() {
      body...
    }*/
  })
}
```

And my ticket controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @ticket = Ticket.all;
    @value = params[:parish]
    puts @value
end
```

This is the conditional `erb`, as you can see it is set up to use the variable from the controller but it doesn't work, but if I replace `@value` with a hardcoded string it works, `puts @value` displays the value in the console so it isn't empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <% @ticket.where(parish: @value).each do |ticket| %>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your log?

Comment: @Gerry no errors, just seeing the variable being printed

Comment: You can't send a data with GET request, only with POST.

Comment: I know, I was under the impression that GET puts the key value pair in the url and params in the controller takes the variables from the URL

Comment: Try changing `<% @ticket.where(parish: @value).each do |ticket| %>` to `<% Ticket.where(parish: @value).each do |ticket| %>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ***not*** with the `@value` but ***with the query*** you are using in the view. This `<% @ticket.where(parish: @value).each do |ticket| %>` is ***wrong*** as `@ticket` is an ***ActiveRecord collection*** not an ***ActiveRecord model***, so it won't work. You should do

```
<% Ticket.where(parish: @value).each do |ticket| %>
```

But it is ***not the elegant way*** to have a query in a view which will make a DB call, also keeping in mind that `@value` depends on `params[:parish]` I would do

```
def index
  unless params[:parish].nil?
    @tickets = Ticket.where(parish: params[:parish])
  else
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

and in the view

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work, I am getting a better result, previously the map would move to the middle of the sea with 0 markers, when I select a parish it just kinda refreshes and shows all markers still so not working like when hardcoded

Comment: @the_islander What is the value of `parish` in the `params` look like?

Comment: puts params[:parish] prints kingston when I select that from the dropdown which should work as the string "kingston" works. I compared the SQL statement the variable and hardcoded string produces and they are the same so this is weird